# PHP MySQL not inserting data into the database and returning product id as 0

Tags: php, mysql

I cant seem to get this function to enter the data into the database and return the product_id. When I try returning the product_id it returns 0 along with nothing entered into the database

PHP Function:

```
function product_id(){
    $id_data = "INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `date_created`) VALUES('', NOW())"; 
    mysqli_query(database(), $id_data);

    return $product_id = mysqli_insert_id(database());
}
```

MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE products(
product_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

Here is how I call the function in PHP

```
$product_id = product_id();
```

Comment: Careful with functions like `database()`. The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` response is a *per connection* local, so other connections will have no idea what this one did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot insert into an `auto_increment` field remove it from the insert statement and it should work.

```
function product_id(){
    $id_data = "INSERT INTO `products` (`date_created`) VALUES( NOW())"; 
    mysqli_query(database(), $id_data);

    return $product_id = mysqli_insert_id(database());
}
```

Also you were likely getting a `mysqli` error in the future try using the `mysqli_error()` function

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it explicitly to insert zero:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `date_created`) VALUES('', NOW())
```

That empty string gets cast to an INT and set to zero. Since it's an autoincrement field, just leave it out and it will pick the next available value:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`date_created`) VALUES(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a value of  NULL for your product id by using `VALUES('',NOW())`.

You do not need to provide a value or define it in your query for `product_id` since it is an auto-increment primary key as your `create table` query states.

The code below, without defining the product_id explicitly in the insert query, should work just fine:

```
function product_id(){
  $id_data = "INSERT INTO `products` (`date_created`) VALUES( NOW())"; 
  mysqli_query(database(), $id_data);

  return $product_id = mysqli_insert_id(database());
}
```